# Image summaries with TensorFlow 2 Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, summary

How can I create an image summary in tensorboard using tensorflow >2? It is clear to me how I should do with tensorflow 1 (e.g. using placeholder), but I'm not sure about the new tensorflow.

This is my current code:

```
# create dataset using tf.data.Dataset :
train_data = create_dataset_pipeline(train_filenames)  # returns (image, mask) pairs
valid_data = create_dataset_pipeline(valid_filenames)  # exactly as train_data, but on different images

# define a model:
model = UNet()

# train model:
for image, mask in train_data:
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      predictions = model(image, training=True)
      loss = weighted_cross_entropy(predictions, labels)

   # apply gradients
   gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
   optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

   # ....
```

And during the validation step, I'd like to show some examples of an input image, and the respective model prediction and ground-truth segmentation mask.

```
with writer.as_default():
   tf.summary.image("Validation", ????, step=0, max_outputs=3)
```

What should I put in `????`?

Comment: Have you consulted [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image)? It says `data` should be "A `Tensor` representing pixel data with shape `[k, h, w, c]`, where `k` is the number of images, `h` and `w` are the height and width of the images, and `c` is the number of channels, which should be 1, 2, 3, or 4 (grayscale, grayscale with alpha, RGB, RGBA). Any of the dimensions may be statically unknown (i.e., `None`). Floating point data will be clipped to the range [0,1)".

Comment: Sorry but this is confusing to me (I was programming in tf 1 until a few days ago). The output of tf.data.Dataset is a tensor, right? what happens when I iterate over the dataset, exactly? Can you show me an example, please (I find the documentation a bit unclear on this)?

Comment: When you iterate over a dataset, you get the tensors in it. If `image` is a batch of images (you can check its shape simply with `print(image.shape)`), then you should be able to do `tf.summary.image("Validation", image, step=0, max_outputs=3)`.

Comment: I see, but then, I'm forced to have the summary writer inside the for loop, I cannot just have a separate function with all the summaries (old tensorflow fashion) that I call at validation time (like one could do after summaries.merge(.))

Comment: You can create the summary writer before the for loop and pass it as a parameter to the summary-writing function, which would then create the `writer.as_default()` context within it.

Comment: Great. Let's consider this example: I have the training loop, and inside of it I call `write_image_summaries(image, writer, step)`. Inside the function I define a `tf.summary.image(..., max_output=3)`. This means that, even if my training loop iterates 100 times, the summary will just write the first 3 images? or will it keep overriding the last 3 images it gets? (basically, I wonder how efficient is this)

Comment: That's what the `step` parameter is for, you aren't supposed to create two summaries with the same label and step, if you increase the step number then each three images should be added to TensorFlow associated to a different step.

Comment: Great, so until I leave the step fixed I'm sure that no computation is wasted adding new logs to tensorboard. How is this handled under the hood by TF? is there something like `if step > old_step: write summary(); else: pass` ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the details, but I think the writer doesn't do anything smart like that, if you write two events of the same type with the same label and step both of them will go into the log file I think. It's then up to TensorBoard to decide how to present the information, if the logs are not consistent it may not show up as you expect (maybe it's smart and it just puts together images from different events, or maybe just picks the last ones you recorded, or something else).